# $d,k$ - codes for error detection and correction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, information-theory, coding-theory

My question may sound a bit strange but I'm trying to find out anything about the $d,k$-codes. I've been give a kind of home task to learn what is d,k-code and how it works. The problem is I can't find anything about such kind of code. After some investigations, I asked my lecturer again about the task and got the same answer: find out what are $d,k$-codes and how they work(he's a bit strange). Now I'm not sure that they exist at, so can you you please help me to understand what this codes are?

Comment: The key parameters of a [linear code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code) are often denoted $(n,k,d)$, and my (educated) guess is that this is what your task is about. Use the tag *coding-theory* here to look for related questions, if the above  Wikipedia article seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Forget the $d,k$ for the time being. You have been asked to find out something about "codes for error detection and correction". That gives you all the keywords and keyphrases you could possibly want to start a search, whether on the web or at the library. Then just have faith that the resources you find will tell you what $d$ and $k$ are all about.